# PL/SQL code Template

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to convert a 9 digit number to 10 digit by appending a 0 to it. 
For example In Table ABC say there is a column named B which takes a number which is at the max 10 digit long.

Now sometimes I will get a 9 digit number only.
So in that case when a 9 digit number is faced i need to fire a trigger to make it 10 digit and then insert in the table.

Comment: You talk about a "number".  Is the column actually declared as a `number`?  If it is, leading 0's will be ignored.  The number 0001 will be stored as 1.  Or are you referring to a `varchar2` column that happens to have just numeric characters?

Comment: As Justin says, number is just saved as whole number despite the 0s you append in front. If you want to display the number with a leading 0,or save it as varchar(saving as string is not good idea too).. try to_char(99,'FM0999999999').. Also if you change your column to number, probably still you need not change your code. And it is how it has to be IMO. You gain full usage of all number functions available, and avoid a unwanted conversion from String to Number.

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to create the column with character datatype so that it can hold the leading zeros.

You don't need to write any trigger for this simple operation. you can use lpad for this purpose:

eg.g

```
Insert into table1(number_col) values ( lpad(999999999, 10, '0'));

select * from table1;

| number_col      |
|-----------------|
|      0999999999 |
```

To use this in trigger, create a trigger as follows (Not Tested);

```
create or replace trigger trg_table1
before insert or update of number_col on table1
 for each row
begin
  :new.number_col := lpad( :new.number_col, 10, '0' );
end;
```

Comment: My requirement is Whenever a row is inserted i need to check length of the G2R(Column name) if its less than 10 i need to make it 10 by appending a zero.

Comment: @user2911939 : The second parameter of lpad will take care of it, lpad(999, 10, '0') will tell Oracle to append 0 to the left of 999 until its length becomes 10.

Comment: @ San : I know the lpad operation..but my problem is the insert is at way too many places.. that way am trying to reduce the number of lines i need to edit .Somebody gave me the idea of using a trigger but am not sure how to...

Comment: @user2911939 : Updated the post for trigger

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to make this a trigger. Adding a 0 to the front of the number is really only for humans, the computer doesn't care and that information can't be stored in the database unless you convert the column to a string format.

What you're looking for is one of three things: Either, change the way your forms display the information to add padding if the number is less 10,000,000,000 to affect the way the user sees the information (most recommended)

Or, use the lpad function to convert the number to a string with 0 padding if necessary

```
lpad(input,10,'0')
```

Note that this will require conversion back to a number to insert into the DB if it is possible for the user to edit this number. (second most recommended)

Lastly, you can always store the value in a string format and use lpad as above on insert.
I wouldn't recommend this as strings take up much more space than numbers, and the db won't search them as fast. Also, why store a number as a string purely for the user's sake, when you can change the way your data looks to the user programatically?